# Math.floor on a math calculation

Tags: android, math, android-studio, floor

I have made an calculation, took of the decimals but now i would like to make so that it show a down rounded number.
I found that i can use math.floor but i can't get it in the code.
I took the decimals off but can't get it to round down.

code is like this (the part which does the math):

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (etBarfles.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vul zowel bar in fles, inhoud fles als liters per " +
                "minuut in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        if (etInhoudfles.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vul zowel bar in fles, inhoud fles als liters per " +
                    "minuut in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (etLitersperminuut.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Vul zowel bar in fles, inhoud fles als liters " +
                        "per minuut in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
            }
            tvResult.setText(nodecimals((((Float.parseFloat(etBarfles.getText().toString()) *
                    (Float.parseFloat(etInhoudfles.getText().toString())) / (Float.parseFloat
                    (etLitersperminuut.getText().toString()))) / 60))));
        }
    }
}

private String nodecimals(float val) {
    return String.format("%.0f", val);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
tvResult.setText(String.valueOf((int) Math.floor(((Float.parseFloat(etBarfles.getText()
                .toString()) *
                (Float.parseFloat(etInhoudfles.getText().toString())) / (Float.parseFloat
                (etLitersperminuut.getText().toString()))) / 60))));
```

`(int) Math.floor()` will convert the value to an integer floor value, and then `String.valueOf()` will convert that `int` to `String`, so that you can set the same to the `TextView`.

**THINGS TO IMPROVE:**
You can make your code better by following these guidelines:

1. You are using the same line `etBarfles.getText().toString()` in multiple places for your check conditions. Its best if you initialize a variable with that value. Something like

   `String etBarFilesText = etBarfles.getText().toString();`
2. Your condition `etBarfles.getText().toString().equals("")` can be written the `Android` way as follows

   `!TextUtils.isEmpty(etBarFilesText)`
3. Your strings should be defined in your `strings.xml`. So if your error msgd is named `error_string` in the `strings.xml` then your `Toast` message will look something like this.

   `Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_string), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`
4. Your line

   `tvResult.setText(nodecimals((((Float.parseFloat(etBarfles.getText().toString()) *
                       (Float.parseFloat(etInhoudfles.getText().toString())) / (Float.parseFloat
                       (etLitersperminuut.getText().toString()))) / 60))));`
   could have been wayy simpler, and more readable if you used different variables, instead of writing everything in a big single sentence.

Comment: Check my updated answer for the things that you can improve in your code.

Comment: I am learning,that's why i ask questions, this helps me a lot!!